# Event scheduling

Tags: algorithm

You are given a set of *n* jobs. Each job is associated with a starting time and an ending time, both represented as integers, and the profit you would make from it. You have to determine which jobs to take to maximize profit, keeping in mind that only one job can be done at any one time. Is there an  algorithm for this with better than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** efficiency?

Comment: yes I had a solution which is O(n^2).Used map to sort based on start and end time and then iterated and updated ,bt time limit exceeds.I need something better

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a little too broad for this site. We focus on specific problems here, not providing complete solutions to general assignments. Could you show us your existing solution? It'd give us a starting point to make suggestions from.

Comment: okk i will edit the post and update my code,bt have to format it a bit ,as i use a lot of different keywords for typing faster

Comment: What constraints prevents me from just answering "take all" in O(1) time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm :

Given set S = {I1,I2,...,In}:

- Sort the intervals in S according to the starting time from low to high.

Now we have ordered set {J1,J2,...,Jn}. (with W1,W2,...,Wn as profits)

We define a(i) as the minimum index k, such start time of Jk is higher than the end time of Ji. Return -1 if no-one exist.

Denote D[i] as the maximum profit (as you described) on the set {Ji,Ji+1,...,Jn}.

So we get:

```
D[-1] = 0;
D[i] = maximum{D[i+1],Wi + D[a(i)]}.
```

- Return D[0].

Run-Time:

Sorting n intervals - O(nlogn).

Construct D - O(n).

Overall run-time = O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is called weighted interval scheduling and can be solved in O(nlogn) steps - or even O(n) if jobs are already sorted.

Quick Google search will give you all the information you'll need about it.